# Creating a for loop with the same style

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

**This is what I want 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.**
They should all be styled the same.

**But when I run my code I only get (5);**

Can someone please help?

```
<p id= "text-1"> this </p>

p#text-1{
  color:blue;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:10px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:gold;
  text-align:center;
}

function forloop(){
  for( x = 0; x<=3; x++){
  document.getElementById('text-1').innerHTML = x;
  }
}
forloop();
```

Comment: I can't believe you actually get 5 from this at all `x <= 3`. Please post your actual code.

Comment: This is the link  to what I am trying to make, and yes you  are right it's not 5 it 3.

Comment: http://codepen.io/2bu/pen/zNWvWo

Comment: You're setting `innerHTML` of the same element in a loop. Each time you're overwriting what you wrote the last time.

Comment: How would I go about getting the effect of what I am trying to do. I need to see something to understand what to make it right.

Comment: I also tried to remove to the .innerHMTL, it still did not work

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to programatically create a list going from 1 to 3, then you can do it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p#text-1{
        color:blue;
        font-size:20px;
        padding:10px;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background:gold;
        text-align:center;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function forloop(){
        var MAX = 3;
        for( x=1; x<=MAX; x++) {
          document.getElementById('text-1').innerHTML += x;
          if(x < MAX) {
            document.getElementById('text-1').innerHTML += ", ";
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="forloop()">
    <p id= "text-1"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that just based on what you've said here, it would be simpler to just put the contents you want into the page directly.  This answer is based on the assumption that you won't always want a list of exactly 3 numbers.

Note also that your div is not wide enough to contain all 3 numbers.  You will need to make sure that your styling is what you want, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

EDIT: If you want each number in its own box, then it will be changed like so:

```
    <style>
     span.numblock {
        color:blue;
        font-size:20px;
        padding:10px;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background:gold;
        text-align:center;
     }
    </style>
```

and

```
    <script>
      function forloop(){
        var MAX = 3;
        for( x=1; x<=MAX; x++) {
          document.getElementById('text-1').innerHTML += "<span class='numblock'>"+x+"</span>";
          if(x < MAX) {
            document.getElementById('text-1').innerHTML += ", ";
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

The onload() was just to get the script to run.  You might not need it, depending on the context in which this will exist.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is close to the effect that I am trying to create. Think of each number as square, with a padding of 20 px around all sides. Each number should have it's own square with the same padding of 20px. Im not sure if im being clear, but it's the best way to explain the effect. Also why do I need an onload?